# Query returns different results in MySQL and mysql client

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-22.04

I tried to get database size, and expected to get same results from MySQL Workbench and MySQL client on Ubuntu server 22.04. I used same user and password for database access.

In MySQL Workbench query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH),0) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='zabbix'
```

returns:

[image]

but, in mysql client, same query:

MariaDB [(none)]>

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH),0) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='zabbix';`
```

returns:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| COALESCE(SUM(DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH),0) |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                           0 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

The exact value of db size is the one from MySQL Workbench (different from 0).

What have I done wrong in MySQL Client?

Comment: Could it be that the users making the request differ from one case to the other ? and so their access permissions on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

Comment: Thanks, challet! user was the same (zbx_monitor), but privileges on local (`zbx_monitor`@`localhost`) and remote user (`zbx_monitor`@`%`) was different. Thanks again.